# CancelInvoke doesn't actually cancel anything

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a function `ReadDataFromBHI()` that will initialize a serial port then open it, then uses `InvokeRepeating` to read the data at `3 sec` intervals.

It's working fine, the problem is it won't stop.

I have a disconnect button that calls `ClosePorts()` when clicked. As you can see the `ClosePorts()` is supposed to `CancelInvoke` the `ReadDataContinuously` and has a Boolean flag that sets to false, this isn't working either. The `ReadDataContinuously` continues to read data and print to the console window.

Any help getting this to stop?
Thanks

I have tried adding a boolean flag to the `ClosePorts()` method and setting it to false.  This isn't stopping it.

Have also tried `CancelInvoke()` without the qualifying string.

```
public class ReadPortData : MonoBehaviour       // Comes here when 'connect' is clicked, to start reading serial port data
{
    public TMP_Dropdown portName;
    public TMP_Dropdown baudRate;
    public TMP_Dropdown dataBits;
    public TMP_Dropdown stopBits;
    public TMP_Dropdown parity;

    private string spName;
    private int baud;
    private int dB;
    private int sB;
    private string pRity;
    private static bool connected;

    public SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();


    private void ReadDataFromBHI()
    {
        //   First get the values that were selected on the pnlComms dropdowns

        ClosePorts();

        spName = portName.options[portName.value].text;
        baud = int.Parse(baudRate.options[baudRate.value].text);
        dB = int.Parse(dataBits.options[dataBits.value].text);
        sB = int.Parse(stopBits.options[stopBits.value].text);
        pRity = parity.options[parity.value].text;


        sp.PortName = spName;
        sp.BaudRate = baud;
        sp.DataBits = dB;
        sp.DtrEnable = true;

        switch (sB)
        {
            case 0: sp.StopBits = StopBits.None; break;
            case 1: sp.StopBits = StopBits.One; break;
            case 2: sp.StopBits = StopBits.Two; break;
        }

        switch (pRity)
        {
            case "None": sp.Parity = Parity.None; break;
            case "Odd": sp.Parity = Parity.Odd; break;
            case "Even": sp.Parity = Parity.Even; break;
        }


        sp.Open();

        Debug.Log(spName + sp.IsOpen);

        connected = true;

        InvokeRepeating("ReadDataContinuously", 3f, 3f);
    }


    public void ClosePorts()        // Closes all the open ports
    {
        CancelInvoke("ReadDataContinuously");

        connected = false;

        string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

        foreach (string s in ports)
        {
            if (sp.IsOpen)
            {
                sp.Close();
                Debug.Log(s + " is now closed");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log(s + " is already closed");
            }
        }
    }

    public void ReadDataContinuously()
    {
        Debug.Log(connected);

        if (connected)
        {
            string buf = "";
            string s;
            string witsItem;
            string witsData;

            buf += sp.ReadExisting();

            Debug.Log(buf);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the `CancelInvoke("string")` or the Boolean flag to stop the serial port from reading data, neither is working.

Comment: Just a general hint: To avoid typos instead of literal strings rather use `nameof(ReadDataContinuously)`. Where/How is `ReadDataFromBHI` called?

Comment: derHugo, I am not sure how to make the formatting you suggested.  I've only had a few posts here still learning the basics.  ReadDataFromBHI() is called from another button's (btnConnect) On Click event on the same panel.  I have 2 buttons on the panel btnConnect and btnDisconnect.  Both have the ReadPortData script attached.  The btnConnect OnClick is pointing at ReadPortData.ReadDataFromBHI function.  The btnDisconnect OnClick event is pointing at ReadPortData.ClosePorts function.

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of `ReadPortData` at the same time? I am thinking that `InvokeRepeating` and `CancelInvoke` works by instance-based rather than static based.

Comment: I only have a single instance of ReadPortData.  The Boolean flag is working as it should, when it gets set to false  Debug.Log(buf) no longer gets printed out, however Debug.Log(connected) continues to get printed out every 3 sec so the CancelInvoke didn't work.